# Make a scrollbar stay visible on content that is too big

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'm creating a data grid using div's.  I need the data in the grid to scroll with the headers in the x direction which works properly in the example.  My problem is I want the headers to always remain visible at the top of the grid so I put the grid's data in another div and use it scroll in the Y direction.  Because the data rows are wider than the parent div, the Y scroll bar is usually not visible. You have to scroll all the way to right to use the Y scroll bar.  Is there any way to keep the scroll bar visible at all times?  I've tried different options with css overflow but can't seem to find the right solution.

[working example of scroll problem](https://emedtrax.com/dg_scroll.html)

Comment: I've only seen this solved with JS -- not with pure HTML.  As an example, they'd put overflow scroll on the body and overflow: hidden on the header.  And whenever the body is scrolled they'd set the margin/offset of the header so the two stay in sync.  Anyway, the solution, in my opinion, is to get a good JS grid and use it instead of cooking your own.  It's a pain to keep them in sync.

Comment: have you had a look at dataTables? I implemented a dataTables table the other week and had an issue similar to this, there is thankfully a setting in the initialization, or some other setting that gets it working fine. If you're interested the link is http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: also have a look at,, http://www.rickyh.co.uk/css-position-x-and-position-y/

Comment: I think it's a usability issue to have to scroll right to see the data. I have this prejudice against horizontal scrollbars.  Can you rearrange the layout so that users aren't trying to see lots of data in a tiny little box?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try, it might work

```
html {
       overflow-x: scroll;
}
```